# one and only one line per optional element using jinja

Tags: jinja2

I have three choices, A/B/C.  If all are chosen I want to render this:

```
   [
      A,
      B,
      C,
   ]
```

If only A and C, I want this:

```
   [
      A,
      C,
   ]
```

If only B, I want this:

```
   [
      B,
   ]
```

If none are chosen, I want this:

```
   [
   ]
```

I have tried many combinations and can't seem to hit on something that is generalizable to a list of arbitrary length.

For example this works fine if all are chosen:

```
   [
{% if include_A %}      A,{% endif %}
{% if include_B %}      B,{% endif %}
{% if include_C %}      C,{% endif %}
   ]
```

But if only A and B are chosen, it gives this:

```
   [
      A,
      B,

   ]
```

Now if I strip the whitespace after the C template with `-%}` like this:

```
   [
{% if include_A %}      A,{% endif %}
{% if include_B %}      B,{% endif %}
{% if include_C %}      C,{% endif -%}
   ]
```

Then it also ends up stripping the whitespace before the `]`:

```
   [
      A,
      B,
]
```

Stripping the whitespace using `{%-` at the beginning of the C template works for the AB case:

```
   [
{% if include_A %}      A,{% endif %}
{% if include_B %}      B,{% endif %}
{%- if include_C %}      C,{% endif %}
   ]
```

But it fails for the ABC case, this time rendering this:

```
   [
      A,
      B,      C,
   ]
```

Is what I am wanting even possible with Jinja?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I think I hit upon something.  It seems those `{%-` and `-%}` whitespace-eating things are very greedy.  If I avoid those and make all newlines explicit, I can do it like this, by checking for B on the same line as A:

```
   [{% if include_A %}
      A,{% endif %}{% if include_B %}
      B,{% endif %}{% if include_C %}
      C,{% endif %}
   ]
```

But it's just a tad ugly since the concerns of A and B get mixed up on the same line of source code (as well as B and C)...

So then I figured out that this also works:

```
   [
{% if include_A %}      A,
{% endif %}{% if include_B %}      B,
{% endif %}{% if include_C %}      C,
{% endif %}   ]
```